# Nested Accordian FAQ

Tags: plugins

I have developed plugin for the FAQs accordion with custom post type. But now I have to add functionality for nested FAQs.

For example FAQ 1 contain another accordion with no. of questions.

I have to make like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Nested-Accordion-Plugin-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-multiAccordion/ by shortcode or something.

Please give me suggestion how to build this.

Comment: what does it even mean "nested FAQs"? Please edit your question and add more details and relevant code

Comment: I have to make like this dynamic in WordPress 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Nested-Accordion-Plugin-with-jQuery-jQuery-UI-multiAccordion/